# Node.JS and Nodemailer having a memoryleak?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have a rather simple Node.JS application that uses subscribe to redis to receive messages which it then sends out to the connected clients.  In addition I also use the subscribe method to pass Node.JS the command to send out emails to our users.

All works well but the memory usage grows daily until it reaches 1.1GB (using command top on linux) and then all further email sending fails with the error message:

```
{ [Error: spawn ENOMEM] code: 'ENOMEM', errno: 'ENOMEM', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

Where could that come from? The source code is rather simple:

Clients connecting:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    nClients++;
    console.log("Number of clients connected " + nClients);
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        nClients--;
        console.log("Number of clients remaining " + nClients);
    });
});
```

Receiving messages to send out to the clients

```
cli_sub.on("message",function(channel,message) {
    if(nUseDelay==1) {
        oo = JSON.parse(message);
        ablv_last_message[oo[0]["base"]+"_"+oo[0]["alt"]] = message;
    } else {
        io.sockets.emit('ablv', message);
    }
});
```

Sending out emails to clients

```
cli_email.on("message",function(channel,message) {
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("sendmail");

    oo = JSON.parse(message);

    var mailOptions = {
        from: email_sender,
        bcc: oo["bcc"],
        to: oo["recipient"],
        subject: oo["subject"],
        html: oo["text"]
    } 
    try {
        transport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});


setInterval(function() {
        Object.keys(ablv_last_message).forEach( function(key) {
        io.sockets.emit('ablv', ablv_last_message[key]);
    });
    ask_last_message = [];
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `nodemailer.createTransport` you're creating a pool of SMTP connections that's intended to be reused for the life of your application.

So change your code to call that once at your app's startup and then reuse the `transport` object each time you need to send an email.

Comment: OK, I'll change the code and observe for a day. But why wouldn't it clean up properly the local variable and the associated pool? Btw, leaving var mailOptions as a local variable is ok or should that also be moved to a global variable scope?

Comment: Because it still has an open connection that's keeping it from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Moving the var transport; out of the function alone isn't sufficient, the memory continuously increases. I now moved the var mailOptions also to a global declaration. Lets see how this works out.

Comment: I am closing this question, the mail topic has helped to slow down the memory leak but it most be another part of the code too. I'll post another question on that.

Comment: @JohnnyHK any link to support the one transport for the lifetime of app statement?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, @JohnnyHK Did moving the transport ever solve the issue ?